# How to display an inputText when specific selectOneMenu option is selected?

Tags: java, ajax, jsf, jsf-2, selectonemenu

I want to create settings panel for application. The application will store the settings values into database table. The settings panel will be used to display the settings and change the values. I want to represent the values in this way:

[image]

[image]

This way the user will be able to enter only fixed values. I want to give a change to the user to enter custom values. Like this:

[image]

I want to create `selectOneMenu` with option `custom`. When the user selects `custom` the `selectOneMenu` will be replaced with `inputText` field where he will be able to enter the custom value. `SAVE` button will save the data into database. Is this possible without page reload? Maybe with AJAX?

How this can be implemented?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `<f:ajax>` to display a `<h:inputText>` whenever the current option equals `"custom"`.

```html
<h:selectOneMenu value="#{bean.type}">
    <f:selectItem itemValue="one" itemLabel="Option one" />
    <f:selectItem itemValue="two" itemLabel="Option two" />
    <f:selectItem itemValue="three" itemLabel="Option three" />
    <f:selectItem itemValue="custom" itemLabel="Define custom value" />
    <f:ajax render="input" />
</h:selectOneMenu>
<h:panelGroup id="input">
    <h:inputText value="#{bean.customType}" rendered="#{bean.type == 'custom'}" required="true" />
</h:panelGroup>
```

Comment: Yes. The backing bean code should be obvious enough. The above example assumes two `String` properties `type` and `customType`. You can of course also use `<f:selectItems>` if you need to prepopulate the items dynamically in the bean. For more detail on `h:selectOneMenu` usage, check the tag wiki page: http://stackoverflow.com/tags/selectonemenu/info

Comment: One last question: After the user enters the data how the JSF page must pass the values to the managed bean in order to update them into the database? I suppose that I need form. Something like this: http://pastebin.com/Fq19q5z9

Comment: You already have it, otherwise `<f:ajax>` wouldn't work :) Just add a `<h:commandButton value="Submit" action="#{bean.submit}"/>` with a `public void submit()` method wherein you do the job. See also chapter 1 of a bit decent JSF2 tutorial.

Comment: I updated my code this way: http://pastebin.com/47Qf6vMm But it's not working. When I choose custom from the option menu the field does not self update. Maybe I'm missing something?

Comment: Your value bindings are wrong. It must be bound to a property with a getter/setter pair and not to an action method where JSF would be unable to set the submitted value. Also, you have not changed the `rendered` attribute to the appropriate bean property. For the proper value bindings, see also my answer on one of your previous questions http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9655951/how-to-call-datasource-during-bean-initialization

Comment: I changed the code this way: http://pastebin.com/tCNBLcZ8  Still when I choose custom from the h:selectOneMenu nothing happens. If I change the session value to custom in the managed bean bellow h:selectOneMenu I can see input field. I expected when I choose custom from the h:selectOneMenu the menu to be replaced with input field. Is this possible?

Comment: Why would you want to make the enduser unable to change the dropdown option when he changes mind? Just show the input next to the dropdown.

Comment: Yes this will be better way. Now It works but I want to display the custom input field if the user clicks "custom" from the "h:selectOneMenu". In this code if the variable session is "custom" the input field will appear. And I want if the client clicks other value from the h:selectOneMenu the input field to disappear. Is this possible with ajax without page reload?

Comment: That's already been answered. When you select "custom", the field will appear. When you select another option afterwards, the field will disappear. Have you even tried it yourself?

Comment: Yes I compiled the code and I uploaded it on Glassfish. This is the code. http://pastebin.com/HPwqtHAD Maybe something is missing? If I define into the bean "session = custom" the input field will appear bellow the selectOneMenu. If I choose from the selectOneMenu "custom" nothing happens.

Comment: So the input does not display when you change the menu option to custom? Do you see any JavaScript errors in the console?

Comment: I get this: http://i39.tinypic.com/rwnzo7.jpg   http://i39.tinypic.com/fd59as.jpg   http://i44.tinypic.com/a5chw9.png  These are the steps

Comment: Do you have Firebug? Press F12 and check JavaScript console for any JS errors.

Comment: I installed it. Yes this is the problem: http://i44.tinypic.com/16izlth.png   

throw new Error("jsf.ajax.request: Method must be called within a form");

Comment: So you have really not a `<h:form>`? Add it. From your second comment on I understood that you already have it working...

Comment: Yes now it works. One last thing that I don't understand: I need to update the database with the inserted values. Is this the proper way to create a form? http://pastebin.com/uN6eNFXC Because now if a client click the submit button nothing happens. I suspect that the normal behavior must be method "submit" is not found? But this does not happen.

Comment: The button must be inside the form. The action must point to a valid method.

Comment: And one more thing: I want to use HashMap to get the settings and the values from the database because with one sql query I want to get all settings and values. Then I want to get the content with just pointing the key. Something like this: http://pastebin.com/ZiuQw2dX but I get error then I run the page. You told me that I must use getter/setter to get the values in the h:selectOneMenu. Is there any way to solve this problem?

Comment: P.S: I get this error: serverError: class javax.faces.component.UpdateModelException /Application.xhtml @36,110 value="#{ApplicationController.settingValue('MaxUsersActive')}": Illegal Syntax for Set Operation Is this by JSF design? Maybe in future versions of JSF this will be repaired?

Comment: As said, your value bindings are wrong. Check the "unrelated" note of my answer on your previous question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9655951/how-to-call-datasource-during-bean-initialization No, this is not a JSF bug. This is a bug in your own code.

Answer (score 0):

You can use bootstrap select2 class:

```
<h:selectOneMenu styleClass="form-control input-sm select2"
value="#{myBean.data}" id="data">
</h:selectOneMenu>
```